# In MVC is there a way to Alias the Model Properties to display in a html.Labelfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, model, alias

In my users form I want to use the html.Labelfor  helper, but instead of  Model Property name of CatName, I would like  Category Name Instead. I know I could put this in a , but I have to reuse the names over and over. Below is example.

Model Property:

```
public string CatName { get; set; }
```

VIEW:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatName)  //Displays CatName , I want Category Name
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`DataAnnotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)

```
 [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
 public string CatName { get; set; }
```

This is the preferred way.

You can also use the overload of `LabelFor` that takes a string for the label text

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatName, "Category Name")
```